# Father as an heir

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, family-members, pinchas, estates-inheritance

In [Parashat Pinchas](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0408.htm) we learn about the rules of inheritence. A son inherits first. This is implicit from the first statement of the Parsha. It says that if the deceased person

- didn't have a son, then the daughter inherits ([27:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0427.htm#8)).
- didn't have a child, then the brothers inherit ([27:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0427.htm#9)).
- didn't have children or brothers, then the father's brothers inherit  ([27:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0427.htm#10)).
- didn't have children, brothers or uncles, then the closest relatives inherit  ([27:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0427.htm#11)).

I would have assumed that the father would inherit at least before the uncles if he was still alive. Where should fathers rank on this list and why are they missing?

Comment: I recall someone saying that the "מכה אשר לא כתוב בספר התורה" (Dvarim 28:61) is referring to the death of a son in the life of the father, since that case is skipped in the laws of inheritance, but I can't remember who.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sages discuss on [Bava Basra 109a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.109a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the uncles would only inherit by the virtue of the father, so it is impossible that they precede him. Confirming with this idea, the Rambam clearly states the order in [Nachalos 1:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1170530/jewish/Nachalot-Chapter-1.htm#v3), where he says:

> אם הניח בן יורש הכל. לא נמצא לו בן לעולם מעיינין בזרעו של בן אם נמצא לה זרע בין זכרים בין נקבות עד סוף העולם הוא יורש הכל.לא נמצא לו זרע בן חוזרין אצל הבת היתה לו בת תירש  **לא נמצא לה זרע בת חוזר הירושה לאביו.** לא היה אביו קיים מעיינין על זרע האב שהן אחי המת נמצא לו אח או זרע אח יורש את הכל ואם לאו חוזרין אצל אחות. נמצאת לו אחות או זרעה יורש הכל. ואם לא נמצאת לו זרע אחים ולא זרע אחות הואיל ואין לאב זרע תחזור הירושה לאבי האב. לא היה אבי האב קיים מעיינין על זרע של אבי האב שהן אחי אביו של מת והזכרים קודמין לנקבות וזרען של זכרים קודמין לנקבות
>
> First the son(s) or his (their) decendents if he is no longer alive inherit the deseased, if no son exists the daughter(s) inherit or her decendents, **if no daughters exist the deceased father inherits him,** if his father is not alive then his brothers or their decendents inherit him, if not then sister or their decendents, if not then grandfather if still alive, if not then uncles or their decendents, if not then aunties or their decendents. brothers always preceed sister and even the decendents of brothers alway preceed the sisters.

The [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.27.9?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) in Parshas Pinchos says that the father inheriting before the brothers of the deceased is a Halacha that our rabbis received. Alternatively, the Torah gives the inheritence to the brothers via the Father in a process called *mishmush,* which means when he is alive he takes precedence, but when dead its distributed equally to his sons the deceased brothers via the father in the grave.

> **ונתתם את נחלתו לאחיו** קבלו רז"ל כי האב יורש את בנו כאשר אין לו זרע וכו' ועוד כי הירושה היא בשלשלת הזרע ביוצאי חלציו לא בצדדים א"כ **ונתתם את נחלתו לאחיו** משמוש נחלה שהאב יורש בקבר וממנו תבא לאחים